# Best Asset Pipeline Setup for Ruby on Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am running Rails 3.2.12 and deploying to Heroku.

Currently, to get my css files to update locally I need to run

RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

I was wondering how I can get my asset pipeline to start automatically updating upon sacing again in development mode.

I have read the following article, but I am unsure which set up to follow. I am just using basic scss, nothing crazy.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline

Thank you.

Comment: In development mode, you should have "live" updates locally without running precompile; the pipeline should not compile your assets. Your RAILS_ENV for development should be development. `config.assets.debug = true` should be true in `config/environments/development.rb`. How are you running the server locally?

Comment: If you've precompiled locally you need to delete public/assets or else those will be served instead of what is in app/assets